# Single key hotkey mapping in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am wondering if there is a way to set a single key keyboard shortcut in visual studio. IN al my other editors (Android studio and sublimeText) I have the key [`] mapped to goto line. In visual studio it will not let me assign that. But if I push ctrl first it will.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why you'd want to do that. It would be like mapping the letter A to a command. Makes it hard to type code that uses those characters.

Comment: Yes. But I have never run into that problem ever with the  ~ key. It just simply never comes up in code. Its not really comparable to an 'A' character at all. Its just a fast easy hotkey for repeated use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I **REALLY** do not recommend single-character shortcut, you can do it. After all, you are the master of your system :)

First, create a shortcut with `Ctrl+` or `Shift+`. Close the Studio. Open the user's settings file `CurrentSettings.vssettings` located in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Settings` folder with any text editor. Locate that key binding and simply delete `Ctrl+` part. Save. Done.

Comment: This solution does not work in VS 2012 I added :<Shortcut Command="Edit.GoTo" Scope="Global">`</Shortcut>

Answer (score 0):

This is more a workaround than a solution, but you could create a simple [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script to map the backtick to a Ctl + backtick:

```
`::^`
```

You could even limit the effect to Visual Studio by using the `#IfWinActive` directive.